# Trying to get a bordered image to autofit a flexbox div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

**Scenario :**

- I am having trouble getting an image to autofit a flexbox with a border around it. 
  The image will be dynamically generated so sometimes the width or the height might be the longer side. Sometimes the image will be smaller or larger than the box it should be in, but it should automatically fit the size of the box and retain its proper proportions.

**Tried Case :**

- The best I've come up with is to set both width and height of the image to 100%, and then use `object-fit: contain`.
- However, `object-fit: contain` does not work well with borders. Instead of surrounding just the image the border is surrounding the entire parent div.
- **The Problem:** If there is a tall skinny image it might enlarge or shrink to 30% width and 100% height. I would like the border to be also at the 30% and 100% region as well. However, the border is being placed at the 100% width and 100% height area which is not what I want.

What other method would work better for me here?

Here is a simplified look at my code:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <style>
    html, body { width: 100%; height: 100% }
    #outer {
     width: 100%; 
     height: 100%;
     display: flex;
     background-color: green;
     flex-direction: column
    }
    #top, #bottom {
     flex: 1;
     display: flex;
     border: solid black 1px; 
    }
    #first, #third {
     flex: 1;
     background-color: blue;
    }
    #second {
     flex: 3;
     background-color: yellow;
    }
    #second img {
     border: solid black 5px;
     object-fit: contain;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    </style>
    
    <body>
    <div id="outer">
     <div id="top">
      <div id="first">First</div>
      <div id="second">
       <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x800/faa">
      </div>
      <div id="third">Third</div>  
     </div>
     <div id="bottom">
      Bottom
     </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

If you run the above code snippet you will see the thick border is surrounding the entire parent region (shown in yellow), rather than just appearing around the image itself (pink area).

What can I do so that the border is only around the image itself?

**Clarification**

I need something that meets the following criteria:

- Smaller images are scaled up to meet the size of the parent div
- Larger images are scaled down to meet the size of the parent div
- Images should be proportional (i.e. images must retain their aspect ratio and not become distorted)
- The image should be centered within the parent div
- The image should have a border only around the image and not the larger area
- Code must work for both portrait and landscape images
- In most cases only two sides of the image will touch the parent boundary, leaving the rest of the parent div empty (i.e. the yellow background in my code sample)

I'm actually quite surprised given how far CSS has come that there seems to be no simple solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Used `object-fit: cover`
 so that the image will cover the entire parent.

Other solution will be inserting an image already having a border on it.
Image can be edited online to attach a border to itself.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <style>
    html, body { width: 100%; height: 100% }
    #outer {
     width: 100%; 
     height: 100%;
     display: flex;
     background-color: green;
     flex-direction: column
    }
    #top, #bottom {
     flex: 1;
     display: flex;
     border: solid black 1px; 
    }
    #first, #third {
     flex: 1;
     background-color: blue;
    }
    #second {
     flex: 3;
     background-color: yellow;
    }
    #second img {
     border: solid black 5px;
     object-fit: cover;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    </style>
    
    <body>
    <div id="outer">
     <div id="top">
      <div id="first">First</div>
      <div id="second">
       <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x800/faa">
      </div>
      <div id="third">Third</div>  
     </div>
     <div id="bottom">
      Bottom
     </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Updated Solution:**

 So, to achieve this, we can put image inside a container that will be 
take height and width according to image. Put this image container div inside the main div container.
So, in this case, we have put the following code into `#second` conatiner, and adjusted the corresponding css to achieve the desired result.

```css
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100% }
    
    img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        position: relative;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
}
    #testing {
        display: inline-block;
        /* text-align: center; */
    }
    #outer {
     width: 100%; 
     height: 100%;
     display: flex;
     background-color: green;
     flex-direction: column
    }
    #top, #bottom {
     flex: 1;
     display: flex;
     border: solid black 1px; 
    }
    #first, #third {
     flex: 1;
     background-color: blue;
    }
    #second {
     flex: 3;
     background-color: yellow;
        display: flex;
        margin: 0 auto;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    #second img {
        border: solid black 5px;
        object-fit: contain;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <div id="outer">
     <div id="top">
      <div id="first">First</div>
      <div id="second">
                <div id='testing'>
         
           <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x350/faa">
                </div>
      </div>
      <div id="third">Third</div>  
     </div>
     <div id="bottom">
      Bottom
     </div>
    </div>
<div id="outer">
     <div id="top">
      <div id="first">First</div>
      <div id="second">
                <div id='testing'>
         
           <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x1000/faa">
                </div>
      </div>
      <div id="third">Third</div>  
     </div>
     <div id="bottom">
      Bottom
     </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: The border is still surrounding the parent, rather than the image itself.

Comment: i just went through your code, and from result i thought the overflowing borders should be inside the container. Let me see if i can do anything.
The border is around image only, as the height and width of image is same as parent. So the border is around image itself.

Comment: Thank you. And yes, you are correct. I just modified my code to set `box-sizing: border-box` on the image. It seems to do the same as your code. Do you think one method is preferred over the other?

Comment: i dont know how i missed this property `box-sizing: border-box` its so common, i thought you were struggling to contain image with this property enabled. But, yes its working now, but i thik may be you can try removing `object-fit: contain` as well to see if it works, i think it will.

Comment: Nope, it does not work. If I remove `object-fit: contain` then my object will stretch out of proportion to fill both 100% width and height.

Comment: Nope, it is not answered, because I need the border only around the image itself. Instead, the border is showing up around the 100% width and 100% height area, even if the image is only displayed in 50% width and 100% height.

Comment: I have updated my question with a pink image showing in the code snippet. I am wanting the border around this region, not around the yellow region.

Comment: @kojow7 see, the answer. I know you want the borders around the image but in your code you are providing 100% to both height and width, which will take image height and width according to its parent. So, border applied on image but image is taking as much space as the parent. You can inspect the image to see the height and width taken by the parent and image.

Comment: Correct, that was the best way I could find to get the image to fit the area, while still maintaining its proportions. I am looking for another solution that will get the image to fit within the parent div at its greatest possible size without losing its aspect ratio and having a border around it. Your updated code does not maintain its original aspect ratio so it will not work for me because the image gets distorted. Adding a border as part of the image will not work because I could have thousands of images, and it would be difficult to modify the border if I ever wanted to change it.

Comment: @kojow7 an upvote is highly appreciated if answer is somewhat helpful. Please see the updated solution i have added by manipulating the html part and adjusting css for that.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is working in this particular case, but will not work for an image that has a longer width. i.e. it works for 350x800, but does not work for 800x350.

Comment: For that, either you can make `overflow: hidden` for parent container but problem will be that full image will not be shown, or can allow scrolls in the container with `overflow: auto`

Comment: Yes, neither of those will work for me. I need the full image shown without scrolls.

Comment: @kojow7 atleast half of answer is solved here, i mean for the case if image size is smaller, so please go with the upvote as it can be a solution for a smaller size images. Rest i will look into and will update whenever something helpful is found for larger size images.

Comment: If you find something that works for both smaller and larger images as well as portrait and landscape images I will be able to upvote you and give you the answer. As it stands now my original solution posted in my question is much more usable as the image will not cover other important parts of the screen.

Comment: @kojow7 see the updated answer if its helpful, or do i have to look more into the thing.

Comment: Yes, that's much better now. It still doesn't enlarge the smaller images, but is a step in the right direction.

Comment: @kojow7 give the dimension you are looking for, its almost the complete answer, as i have tested with so many dimensions in the fiddle, and its producing the expected result.For now, its maintaining the aspect ratio, center the image, have border around image and not on the parent. Now, you are going too deep to look for cases with special cases, as in most cases its a working solution.See the answer in `full page` mode and try this code in some fiddle to see results.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want only with height 100%? If not height 100% is depend on image's prop, you can use object-fit: fill; and height:auto;

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <style>
    html, body { width: 100%; height: 100% }
    #outer {
     width: 100%; 
     height: 100%;
     display: flex;
     background-color: green;
     flex-direction: column
    }
    #top, #bottom {
     flex: 1;
     display: flex;
     border: solid black 1px; 
    }
    #first, #third {
     flex: 1;
     background-color: blue;
    }
    #second {
     flex: 3;
     background-color: yellow;
    }
    #second img {
     border: solid black 5px;
     object-fit: contain;
     width: 100%;
     height: auto;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    </style>
    
    <body>
    <div id="outer">
     <div id="top">
      <div id="first">First</div>
      <div id="second">
       <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/800">
      </div>
      <div id="third">Third</div>  
     </div>
     <div id="bottom">
      Bottom
     </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Looking at your code snippet it is clearly not working. Your image is going well outside of the yellow area. It needs to be contained within the yellow area, as large as it can be, and still maintaining aspect ratio.

Comment: Yes sorry, I edited code snippet. " Height: auto;" will border image itself.

Comment: But the image is still going outside of the parent div. It should only be displayed in the yellow space. You likely should see some of the yellow parent around it as most images will not have the exact ratio of the parent div.

Answer (score 0):

did you mean something like this?

changes are, move `width: 100%` and `height: 100%` to parent, add `max-height: 100%` on img, and add `text-align: center` on parent

**update**:
- add another div inside #second
- make #second `display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center`
- add `max-width: 100%` to img
- add `max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%; height: fit-content;` to the added div

```css
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100% }
    #outer {
     width: 100%; 
     height: 100%;
     display: flex;
     background-color: green;
     flex-direction: column
    }
    #top, #bottom {
     flex: 1;
     display: flex;
     border: solid black 1px; 
    }
    #first, #third {
     flex: 1;
     background-color: blue;
    }
    #second {
     flex: 3;
     background-color: yellow;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
      text-align:center;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    #second img {
     border: solid black 5px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      max-height: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
    }
    #vcenter{
      max-height: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
      height: fit-content;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <div id="outer">
     <div id="top">
      <div id="first">First</div>
      <div id="second">
          <div id="vcenter">
       <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x800/faa">
          </div>
      </div>
      <div id="third">Third</div>  
     </div>
     <div id="bottom">
      Bottom
     </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

same code for landscape images

```css
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100% }
    #outer {
     width: 100%; 
     height: 100%;
     display: flex;
     background-color: green;
     flex-direction: column
    }
    #top, #bottom {
     flex: 1;
     display: flex;
     border: solid black 1px; 
    }
    #first, #third {
     flex: 1;
     background-color: blue;
    }
    #second {
     flex: 3;
     background-color: yellow;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
      text-align:center;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    #second img {
     border: solid black 5px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      max-height: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
    }
    #vcenter{
      max-height: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
      height: fit-content;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <div id="outer">
     <div id="top">
      <div id="first">First</div>
      <div id="second">
          <div id="vcenter">
       <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1350x200/faa">
          </div>
      </div>
      <div id="third">Third</div>  
     </div>
     <div id="bottom">
      Bottom
     </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: It's close but it won't work for an image that's 1200 x 50 for example. It is no longer contained within the parent div.

Comment: updated the answer, but i need to add another div for vertical centering, if that's acceptable